# Writing dummy data to the selected file of external storage android

Tags: android, dummy-data, randomaccessfile, android-external-storage

In the below mentioned code I am writing dummy data to all files present in external storage and renaming to "abc.txt". But what I want is to write dummy data to only that file which I select and rename that particular file. How do I do?

```
File[] files = root.listFiles();
for ( File f : files ) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) 
        continue;
    FileChannel rwChannel = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw").getChannel();  
    int numBytes = (int)rwChannel.size();  
    ByteBuffer buffer = rwChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, numBytes); 
    System.out.println("buffer"+buffer);
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[numBytes];  
    new Random().nextBytes(randomBytes);  
    buffer.put(randomBytes);  
    rwChannel.write(buffer);
    rwChannel.close(); 
}
File root1 = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File[] files1 = root.listFiles();
for ( File f : files ) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) 
        continue;
    File myFile1 = new File(root,"abc.txt");
    f.renameTo(myFile1);
}
```

Comment: Select the file that you want to rename using the file name  - `getName()` and then rename it.

Comment: what I want is, to rewrite the contents of each and every file of external storage and then rename them. My first preference to rewriting the contents of a file to dummy data.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaIO/article.html) for how to read and write files.

Comment: what I want is, to rewrite the contents of each and every file of external storage to zero and then rename them. My first preference to rewriting the contents of a file to zeros.